# How to add randomly generated characters in specific locations in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, random, replace

I am working on a problem that requires me to read a string from the file and:

1. Reverse it
2. An integer encryption strength will be defined. It can be
   set to any integer value between 0 and 255.
3. Based on the value of encryption strength, some random letters or digits will be inserted
   between every letter in the reversed string from step 1.

*For example, if the strength was set to 1, the word hello can be encrypted to **o**x**l**a**l**9**e**l**h**.*

*Another example, if the strength is 2, the word hello can be encrypted to
**o**xi**l**4h**l**rc**e**6r**h**.*

My code works overall fine, but the problem is I get repeated random characters inserted between the letters of string, every time.

Here's my code, kindly help me identify the error.

**Code**

```
def encrypt():
    data = "hello"
    content = data[::-1]

    encryption_str = 2
    
    characters = string.ascii_uppercase +string.ascii_lowercase+ 
    string.digits
    
    
    res = (random.choice(characters).join(content[i:i + encryption_str] for i 
    in range(0, len(content)))) #I am stuck here
    
    print(res)
encrypt()
```

**Output**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We expect a *minimal* working example of the problem, including appropriate code to trace the internal operation.  Your file input and reversal are irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Your posted program hangs waiting for input.  Do not expect us to provide test data: simply replace your `input` with a test case that elicits the problem.

Comment: Edited as per your suggestions. @Prune

Comment: The process you describe is not anything like encryption.

Comment: You're telling me that your posted code produces the problem output?  Not yet ...

Comment: It's a beginner level assignment and that's how I am required to do it.

Comment: Edited again and ensured that this time it produces the problem output. @Prune

Comment: @InnovativeAadi Do you understand this sentence which Prune said:   `Your posted program hangs waiting for input. Do not expect us to provide test data: simply replace your input with a test case that elicits the problem.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work fine:

```
import string, random
def encrypt():
    data = "hello"
    content = data[::-1]

    encryption_str = 2

    characters = string.ascii_uppercase +string.ascii_lowercase+string.digits
    res = ""
    res+=content[0]
    for i in range(1,len(content)):
        for j in range(encryption_str):
            res+=random.choice(characters)
        res+=content[i]

    print(res)
encrypt()
```

**Output**

```
oLal5ilWremph
```

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- With `random.choice(characters).join` you are generating *one* random character and use that as (repeated) separator. Instead you would need to repeatedly generate a new random character
- With `content[i:i + encryption_str]` you are slicing characters from the input string that are thus *not* separated.

Here is how you could do it with list comprehension:

```
res = content[0] + "".join(
        ch + "".join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(strength))
        for ch in content[1:]
    )
```

Comment: This was really helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're making this *way* too hard.  All you need is a loop or comprehension that iterates through your content, inserting a pair of random characters.  Since your purpose is obfuscation, rather than anything truly cryptic, I expect that you don't need replacement -- it's okay if you don't have a pair of identical characters inserted.  This lets you take a slight shortcut with `random.sample`.

```
content = "olleh"
result = [content[0]]

for char in content[1:]:
        result.extend(random.sample(characters, 2))
        result.append(char)

print(''.join(result))
```

Output:

```
o8ulTklKBeBTh
```

I'll leave you to collapse it back to a one-liner.