# How to delete randomly inserted characters at specific locations in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, random, del

I was previously working on a problem of String encryption: [How to add randomly generated characters in specific locations in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66835733/how-to-add-randomly-generated-characters-in-specific-locations-in-a-string/66836188#66836188) (obfuscation to be more specific).

Now I am working on its second part that is to remove the randomly added characters and digits from the obfuscated String.

My code works for removing **one** random character and digit from the string (when `encryption_str` is set to `1`) but for removing two, three .. nth .. number of characters (when `encryption_str` is set to `2`, `3` or `n`), I don't understand how to modify it.

**My Code:**

```
import string, random
def decrypt():

    encryption_str = 2 #Doesn't produce correct output when set to any other number except 1

    data = "osqlTqlmAe23h"
    content = data[::-1]
    print("Modified String: ",content)
    
    result = []
    result[:0] = content

    indices = []
    for i in range(0, encryption_str+3): #I don't understand how to change it
       indices.append(i)

    for i in indices:
      del result[i+1]

    message = "".join(result)
    print("Original String: " ,message)

decrypt()
```

**Output for Encryption level 1 (Correct Output)**

[image]

**Output for Encryption level 2 (Incorrect Output)**

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what algorithm you are trying to implement?

Comment: I am showing my work as well. Not simply just dumping the question without any code and asking you all to solve it for me. So am I not supposed to request help when I get stuck in accomplishing a programming task? Is Stack overflow only for experienced developers and not for newbies like me? @Prune

Comment: The sequence of questions indicates that you need help with problem analysis and coding techniques, not merely a single sticking point.  This is out of scope for Stack Overflow.  Please repeat the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for details on the site charter.

Comment: More to your individual situation: when you are able to describe the algorithm you want to implement, but can't get the Python data structure details correct, then you post your code, your output, and your data flow trace -- that's very much what we do here.  However, when your question is essentially "I can't think of how to do this homework problem", then you're in a different audience, better suited for a help site or tutoring service.

Comment: For contrast, see ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This suggests a collection of needs that are too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's easy to append chars, that's a bit more difficult to remove them, because that changes the string length and the position of the chars.

But there is an easy way : retrieve the good ones, and for that you just need to iterate with the `encryption_str+1` as step (that avoid adding an `if` on the indice)

```
def decrypt(content, nb_random_chars):
    content = content[::-1]
    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(content), nb_random_chars + 1):  
        result.append(content[i])
    message = "".join(result)
    print("Modified String: ", content)
    print("Original String: ", message)


    # 3 lines in 1 with : 
    result = [content[i] for i in range(0, len(content), nb_random_chars + 1)]
```

Both will give `hello`

```
decrypt("osqlTqlmAe23h", 2)
decrypt("osqFlTFqlmFAe2F3h", 3)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for such clear explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not try some modulo arithmetic? Maybe with your original string, you try something like:

```
''.join([x for num, x in enumerate(data) if num % encryption_str == 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a list comprehension (which is really just a slightly more compact notation for @azro's answer)?

```
result = content[0::(encryption_str+1)]
```

That is, take every `encryption_str+1`'d character from `content` starting with the first.